# \( \) don't work with TOC?

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, errors, expansion, delimiters

If I write this line of code

```
\subsection{Ranger \( n \) boules distinguables dans \( M \) boîtes}
```

I obtain an error over the second `\)`

```
(./Probabilité.toc

./Probabilité.toc:8: LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

while if I write

```
\subsection{Ranger $ n $ boules distinguables dans $ M $ boîtes}
```

everything is ok.

**Why? `\(\)` has problems with TOC?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\(` and `\)` are not robust, you need to `\protect` them.
Or load package `fixltx2e` that makes them robust.

(Update:) Package `fixltx2e` defines the command `\MakeRobust` that redefines a macro in the same way, as the macro would has been defined by using `\DeclareRobustCommand` in the first place.

"Robust" means, that the macro can be used inside moving arguments (entries for the table of contents, header lines, …) without breaking and the need to add `\protect` in front of them.

Comment: @R.M.: See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764)

Comment: Package `fixltx2e` made it, thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 11):

A short 'aftermath': Since `fixltx2e` content has entered the `LaTeX` Kernel as of 2015/01/01 the `fixltx2e` amendments are available without loading the package.

This means: `\(...\)` is robust now without much further ado!

Heiko Oberdiek's answer is valid anyway for older distributions of course!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Ranger \( n \) boules distinguables dans \( M \) boîtes}
\end{document}
```