# Is there a difference between the latex short hand for math mode and the TeX shorthand for math mode?

Tags: math-mode

If I am typesetting something in LaTeX I can create a math environment using

```
\( a + b = c \)
```

Or I can start math mode using

```
$ a + b = c $
```

Is there a significant difference between the in LaTeX?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74114/dont-work-with-toc/74115#74115

Comment: and for `\[` v `$$` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (The mark for duplication is just one out of many procedures for organizing the site, it's nothing personal. We all hope you will stay with us!)

Comment: @LoverofStructure Thanks! I expected this had been asked, but it was very hard to find the right search term. "$/(" don't tend to be meaningful characters in search engines.